# what is the performance diferrence between RDBMS vs NRDBMS

Tags: database, nosql

I plan to change db from RDBMS  to NRDBMS. So can anyone help and suggest me the performance difference between these two.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which two databases are you switching between?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I plan to change from MYSQL TO NOSQL